# golang: How can i access json decoded field?

Tags: go

i have the next JSON data: http://jsonblob.com/532d537ce4b0f2fd20c517a4

So what im trying to iterate ( like foreach in PHP ) is: invoices -> invoice ( is an array )

So, what im trying to do is:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    json_string := `{"result":"success","totalresults":"494","startnumber":0,"numreturned":2,"invoices":{"invoice":[{"id":"10660","userid":"126","firstname":"Warren","lastname":"Tapiero","companyname":"ONETIME","invoicenum":"MT-453","date":"2014-03-20","duedate":"2014-03-25","datepaid":"2013-07-20 15:51:48","subtotal":"35.00","credit":"0.00","tax":"0.00","tax2":"0.00","total":"35.00","taxrate":"0.00","taxrate2":"0.00","status":"Paid","paymentmethod":"paypalexpress","notes":"","currencycode":"USD","currencyprefix":"$","currencysuffix":" USD"},{"id":"10661","userid":"276","firstname":"koffi","lastname":"messigah","companyname":"Altech France","invoicenum":"","date":"2014-03-21","duedate":"2014-03-21","datepaid":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","subtotal":"440.00","credit":"0.00","tax":"0.00","tax2":"0.00","total":"440.00","taxrate":"0.00","taxrate2":"0.00","status":"Unpaid","paymentmethod":"paypal","notes":"","currencycode":"USD","currencyprefix":"$","currencysuffix":" USD"}]}}`

    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_string), &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    invoices := dat["invoices"]

    fmt.Println("\nJSON-VALUE:",json_string)
    fmt.Println("\nVar type:",invoices)
    fmt.Println("\nVar type using REFLECT:",reflect.TypeOf(invoices))

    for index,value := range invoices.invoice {
        fmt.Println(index,value)
    }

}
```

but im receiving errors like: **invoices.invoice undefined (type interface {} has no field or method invoice)**

http://play.golang.org/p/8uTtN6KtTq

So please, i need some help here, is my first day with Go.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `invoices := dat["invoices"]` the type of `invoices` is `interface{}` which is go speak for could be anything.

In actual fact it is a `map[string]interface{}`.  To turn an `interface{}` into it's concrete type you need to use a [type assertion](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) like this.

```
for index,value := range invoices.(map[string]interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(index,value)
}
```

See [the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SoqIqFuKQU) for full example.

However if this structure is well defined (not all json is) then I'd define a [struct and unmarshal to that](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Unmarshal) which will make your code a lot easier to read.  Don't forget to use Capital letters for your struct names and then name them with the `json:"name"` tags (see [tags in the Marshal section of the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal))